# Is there a way to dynamically size a widget according to whatever the size is left on the screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Lets just say I have 2 widgets on the screen, one a dynamic container that the size depends on the things that are inside that container, and the second widget would be a scrollable ListView. Ideally, I am trying to have both widget on a non scrollable screen, only having the list view to be scrollable. I have tried using a GlobalKey attached to the dynamic container, and then defining the size of the container that's holding the ListView widget with that, but it did not work. This is done on Flutter Mobile development

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. Here is how I would do it-

To limit the height of ListView, wrap the ListView with a Container widget and set the height of the Container to the required height. To make the container cover entire space, wrap with in an Expanded widget. So this is how your widget tree would look like-

//Expanded { //Container { //ListView }}

Comment: I have tried doing so but the expanded brings up warning about "incorrect use of parentdatawidget", and also it expands to the whole size of the list view